# AWS RDS SQL Server RESTORE ISSUE

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, sqlcmd

I created SQL Server res instance on AWS. I want to restore the database from a `.bak` file. I performed below steps in order to restore:

```
sqlcmd -S XXX.rds.amazonaws.com -U root -P XXXX

USE master
go

create database xyzzy

RESTORE DATABASE xyzzy 
FROM DISK = N'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\FMAT_CPS_backup_2017_09_29_040005_9422965.bak'
go
```

but I got this error

> Msg 3110, Level 14, State 1, Server EC2AMAZ-BUJEKP3, Line 1
>   User does not have permission to RESTORE database 'catalyst'.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server EC2AMAZ-BUJEKP3, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

When I tried this command

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlcmd -e -S xxxxrds.amazonaws.com -U root -P xxxx -i "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\FMAT_CPS_backup_2017_09_29_040005_9422965.bak"
```

I got another error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 224 near command 'S' in file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\FMAT_CPS_backup_2017_09_29_040005_9422965.bak'.

The `.bak` file is of 25GB size, I'm not able to open it.

How to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have in-sufficient Permission do you proper IAM Credentials.

Alternatively

You can upload the file to [S3 and Restore to RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore)

Comment: during the time of creation of ms sql aws RDS, I created the master user which is root. and .bak file is on my local system. I logged in with root and trying to restore it.

Comment: post referring to AWS document, I performed below steps,

stored the .bak file to S3 bucket.
Created a new options group and added the SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE option to this option group, during addition option created new IAM role which has access to S3 bucket. And assigned this option group to RDS instance.

Waiting for upload of backup file to finish. Post upload will use below command to restore.

`exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name=‘dynamo', @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::S3Bucket/file.bak’;`

Once I am done, will update with final results.

Comment: upload is done. I tried restoring the database, but I am getting failure. and the exception is "A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown."